# how to display a picture from mysql to a symfony view

Tags: php, mysql, image, symfony4

briefly , i have a table on mysql that i want to display it on a symfony view , it works with all the attributs but i have a problem with the images , i tried this method but still not working!
here my table 
[image: table]
and here my code symfony 
[image: synohanycode]
and finnaly the result 
[image: result]

Comment: please don't use images instead use text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the absolute-path to your images as prefix for the img-src.

I think your images are not available in the url "YOUR_DOMAIN/src/img/". There is probably another path to your images.

Comment: thank you for answering , if there is another path , how can i kno it ?

Comment: try to find your images from browser where you saved them.